# How to Version Control The Baseline Of DB Schema in Liquibase

Tags: sql, liquibase

I currently evaluate how my organisation could make use of liquibase as DB versioning system.

However, I do have difficulties on how the liquibase philosophy fits into our current workflow:

Currently we have the CREATE and initial fill sql scripts of our application under version control. As soon as there is a change (e.g. new column) the programmer adjusts the CREATE script and checks the changes in. Since application code and SQL scripts are in the same repository the DB objects should be always in sync with the application version.

Additionally, for each release we maintain a list of ALTER... statements which are used when the customer upgrades our software (which is much more often the case then installing from the scratch).

So we have two worlds - the current version of the schema objects as CREATE statements in the repository plus a list of necessary actions to get from version 1 to 2 (ALTER statements).

What I like is that the definition of the schema objects always matches the version of the software since the are in the same version control repository.

What I don't like (and hence looking for an alternative) is the double work we have to do. Furthermore, since the software is more updated than newly installed, the CREATE statements are more of a documentation but are rarely applied to the database.

What I understood is, that liquibase starts with a baseline and is then operating on small change sets. So I would once check in the base line and then add my small change sets.

Over the time I might have an old baseline with lots of change sets. I assume I then have to manually generate a new baseline out of old baseline + changesets and start from there again. This sounds rather confusing to me. I'm also not sure if my co-workers would see the benefits compared to our current workflow.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just my opinion, so take it as such.

The Liquibase philosophy is that the baselines you mention are not needed, as long as the database can be queried to see what changes have been applied to it, so your assumption that you would have to periodically generate a new baseline is incorrect.

Let's compare how your process works vs. the Liquibase process.

- In your current system, as you said, developers have to maintain two sets of SQL scripts and your testers have to ensure that they are correct. When users install, your installer has to detect whether it is a clean install and run just the 'create' scripts. When the installer detects an upgrade, it has to take a different path (possibly using some complex logic) to determine which of the alter scripts to run. Your organization has to maintain the installer code that does the upgrade logic.
- Using Liquibase, developers would only create the 'alter' part of the database scripts. For a new install, it might take fractionally longer to run all the Liquibase statements than it would take to run the create scripts in your current system, but the benefit is reduced duplication and therefore reduced bugs. For upgrade installs, Liquibase determines by looking at the installed database which changes are in place and only runs the changes that are necessary to bring the database up to date with the code that is being installed.

Comment: Our install/ upgrade procedure is even less sophisticated - it's a heavily manual process. When you say there is no need for a baseline - how would you connect program source code at a certain revision level with the database objects required?

Comment: Personally, I would keep both the source for the program and the Liquibase change logs in the same source control system, and when creating whatever the distributable artifact was (zip file, installer, etc.) I would bundle them together.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and all the best.

Comment: "For a new install, it might take fractionally longer to run all the Liquibase statements" I wonder how much longer we're talking here. I'm thinking of a system with hundreds of tables which is constantly evolving. Also then a fresh install would probably require migrating in millions of records. One way to do this involves deleting the indexes and then rebuilding them once the data is in place. I wonder how liquibase would handle scenarios like this?

Comment: We are currently doing some performance profiling, so I have some of those numbers. For a new install of a schema with 13,000 tables (and many other objects) on Oracle 11, the difference in time between applying the raw SQL with SQLPlus and doing a deploy with Liquibase is < 1%. Both methods take about 30 minutes.

Comment: Sorry - that is 13,000 changesets - 4200 tables, and lots of other objects.